# Как закэшировать полученный ответ?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

С помощью ajax запроса получаю список городов:

```
function init() {
    let url = "http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/city/";
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((item) => {
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          option.innerHTML = item;
          option.setAttribute("name", "option");
          selected.appendChild(option);
        });
      });
  }
  init();
```

Как потом закэшировать данные в файл используя js и php, чтобы потом:
1)Если файл кэша (произвольный формат, например текстовый) отсутствует - сделать запрос к сервису и сохранить результат в файл.
2)Если файл кэша присутствует и последняя дата его изменения была сегодня - то получать список городов из файла.
3)Если файл есть, но дата изменения - не сегодняшняя, то повторно запросить список городов из сервиса и сохранить в файл.

Не знаю с чего начать, буду признателен хотя бы за ссылки или:
1)Сделать то-то
2)Сделать то-то

Comment: Кеширование на стороне клиента? Мне думается, что если размер данных не велик, то посмотрите в сторону LocalStorage. Если кеширование на стороне сервера, то смотрите документацию к серверу (насколько помню запросы GET хорошо кешируются).

Comment: Скрипт, который формирует данные на стороне сервера вы контролируете или это сторонний сервис? Ваша задача какая - с помощью кеша "разгрузить"  бакенд или клиентскую часть?

Comment: Калькулятор доставки.Есть простой выпадающий список, в который данные поступают из внешнего сервиса  и их надо закэшировать, чтобы потом по пунктам, которые я в вопросе написал.
Задание на php и js.

Comment: такое кешируй на сервере, в базу данных или файлы, я бы не стал запрашивать список городов каждый день. функции работы с файлами  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: В txt файл надо, мне

Comment: Не уверен, как правильно сделать.
Т.е первое, что я так понимаю нужно сделать, это ajax запрос.Это я сделал и вывел данные в тег option.
А потом?Послать post запрос с данными, которые я получил в index.php и проверить, если ли txt файл, если нет, то создать его и записать в него данные из post запроса?

Comment: думаю так, запрос на свой file.php, тот проверяет существует ли кеш и время жизни кеша, если условие не проходит, скачай с сервиса данные и сохрани, затем отдать эти данные js, если же кеш есть, просто отдать данные js

Comment: Вроде понял, спасибо.Сейчас попробую